# Как добавить свой css для кнопок vkontakte

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Проблема следующая. Подключен виджет "Сообщения сообщества" на сайте. Кнопка открытия чата позиционируется не совсем на той высоте что мне бы хотелось. Я решил добавить свой css:

```
.wcm_button .wcm_button_right{
  right: 60px !important;
  position: fixed !important;
  bottom: 40px !important;
}
```

Однако вижу, что он не применяется.

[Вот сайт](http://onedaytv.ru) над которым я работаю, и где сейчас размещена эта кнопка.

Вопрос. Возможно ли как то повлиять на css и если да то как?

Answer (score 1):

Для блока c id `vk_community_messages` пропишите нужный вам стиль.

Comment: я так делал, но это задевает весь блок, так как vk_community_messages является контейнером для всего виджета. Получается если я применю свой сss то вскрытый чат ТАКЖЕ поднимется вверх. А поскольку дизайн всплывающего чата имеет незаконченную нижнюю часть он должен быть всегда внизу. Получается нужно двигать кнопку.

Comment: Внутри `iframe` нельзя применить стили если страница внутри `iframe` не принадлежит вашему домену.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, там же iframe. По сути это другой сайт в вашем сайте, и менять что либо на чужом сайте у вас не получится, доступа внутрь iframe у вас нет из вашего сайта.